# Typescript type inference, spread syntax and multiple type return

Tags: typescript, type-inference, spread-syntax

```
interface SkillProperty {
    [name: string] : number 
};

let skills: SkillProperty;

skills = {}; // ok

skills = { fire: 123 }; // ok

skills = {
    ...skills, // ok
    ...{}, // ok
    ...extraSkills() // {} | { ice: number } is not assignable to type 'SkillProperty'.
}

function extraSkills() {
    if (whatever) {
        return {};
    }
    return { ice: 321 };
}
```

How can I change my `SkillProperty` interface to make it compliant with both empty object and my actual SkillProperty type ?

Comment: This looks like a bug in TypeScript to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SkillProperty` interface *is* actually compatible with `{} | {ice: number}`:

```
let noSkills = {}
let iceSkills = { ice: 321 };
let randomSkills: {} | {ice: number} = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? noSkills : iceSkills
let maybeSkills: SkillProperty = randomSkills; // no error
```

So, this looks like a bug in TypeScript to me.  A similar [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6041) was [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029), but [this case](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6535) seems to persist.  It might be worthwhile opening a new issue with links to those existing ones.

In the mean time there are workarounds, like:

```
skills = {
  ...skills, // ok
  ...{}, // ok
  ...extraSkills() as SkillProperty // okay now
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks ! I noticed that if I explicitly type my function as `extraSkills() : SkillProperty`, it seems to solve the compilation issue. I wanted to see if there is another solution to infer the type